# Google Compute Engine: can't start VM, GCE is not ready

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

After an account verification and payment method update, my VM can't start.

[image: can't start vm]

After my account has been unblocked, I went to my projects, had to activate billing (which I don't get why coz my vms were working before).

One of my project went smooth, vm restarted etc.

On the other one, waited 1h and tried again, got the same error as above..

I can create a new vm IF, and only if, I use a non default VPC. (don't understand why)

So I detached my vm's disk and tried to create a new vm with the old disk attached and a custom VPC, with no chance. The disk seems linked to a default VPC.

Any idea on what can be done?

Comment: Please provide more details about your issue: **1**. Why your account was blocked? **2**. Do you have issues with other VMs in this project? **3**  Do you have default networks listed in your project?

Comment: As requested, more info: account was blocked because of credit card expiration, hence rejected payments. All VMs in this projects are facing the same problem. I created a custom VPC, which allows me to create a new VM when I use it, but even with this vpc I can't create a VM using an existing disk

Comment: Thanks! Have you tried to contact with [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support) to ensure that billing was fully restored for your project?

Comment: Yes, th -e billing has been fully restored and the billing team told me that GCE were up on their side :/

Comment: Have you as solved you issue with Billing Support team?